# BeautifulSoup Scraping Returning Duplicate Results

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract equipment names from [here](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Hero_equipment_A_through_J) using the below code, but my output returns each item about 26 times. I have tried finding a suitable solution and have come up empty-handed. Any thoughts on how to make this work would be appreciated.

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')

for table in tables:
if table.find_parent("table") is not None:
    for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
        for td in table.find_all('td'):
            for a in td.find_all('a'):
                f2.write(a['title'] + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go by parts, first how to get all the heroes names in the table:

```
heroes = soup.find_all('span', {'style': 'white-space:nowrap'})
for hero in heroes:
    print hero.getText()
```

to print all the equipment:

```
eqs = soup.find_all('div', {'style': 'margin:7px 5px 0px;vertical-align:top;text-align:center;display:inline-block;line-height:normal;width:120px;'})

for equipment in eqs:
    print equipment.getText()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this code that works. I am trying to figure out why it works though. From what I see in the source the text actually appears before div style that your code pulls from. Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: @Timmay, it's really easy, if you see the source HTML of the site you are tryin to scrape, you will see that every equipment entry starts with `<div style ...>` so with Beautifulsoup you just need to find all those tags and simply print the TEXT of those, which in this case is the name of the equipment

Comment: Ok. So looking at the code in tree form, the text does appear after your line of code. I guess that is why prettifying the code comes in handy.